# Generating Shareable Messenger Links for Users in Facebook Graph Comment Responses

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am currently utilizing the Facebook Graph API to retrieve comments on specific posts. The response I receive from the API looks something like the following:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "message": "43211234",
      "created_time": "2021-01-09T05:33:14+0000",
      "from": {
        "name": "USER NAME",
        "id": "USER ID"
      },
      "id": "COMMENT ID"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "M...",
      "after": "M.."
    },
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/10...."
  }
}
```

The response appears to be satisfactory, but I have an additional requirement. Alongside the retrieved comments, I would like to obtain shareable messenger links for the users who have commented. This will allow me to initiate conversations with those individuals at a later time.

I have attempted to find a solution for this requirement but have been unsuccessful thus far. I have searched through available resources but haven't come across any relevant information.

I kindly request your assistance in finding a suitable solution or any insights that could help me achieve the generation of shareable messenger links for users who have commented through the Facebook Graph API.

Thank you for your valuable support!

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean by _“shareable messenger link of the user”_.

Comment: by _“shareable messenger link of the user”_ I mean, when I go to that link the messenger will open and I can start messaging with that person.

Comment: Not sure if that is possible. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/m-me-links is how it works for pages, and I think it works the same way for users - but it needs the user name, and you can not get that any more from the API.